# lmer function in R-understading the formula structure in lmer4

Tags: r, lme4

I am a novice. I wonder, like the formula

```
lmer(extro~1+open+social, data)
```

or

```
lmer(extro~open+social+(1+agree|school),data)
```

or

```
glm(extro ~ open + agree + social + school*class - 1, data)
```

what is the meaning of `1` playing as the predictor variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` indicates an intercept. By default, intercepts are always present, so `1 +` doesn't actually add anything, but it can make it explicit that an intercept is being estimated, which can be useful for clarity. `- 1` signals that an intercept should not be estimated. Another way to do this is `0 +`.

In `lmer()`, when including random effects, including `1` is sometimes necessary but always useful. `(1|school)` means you want to estimate a random intercept that varies by `school`. `(1 + open|school)` means you want to estimate a random intercept and a random slope for `open`. Another way to write this is `(open|school)` because the intercept is implicit. This is bad practice because it's ambiguous whether a random intercept is being requested, whereas when including `1 +` it is explicit. It's possible to estimate models with a fixed intercept but a random slope; to do this, you could include `(open - 1|school)`.